# How to rename file with powershell and add alphabetic character to each file name?

Tags: windows, automation, powershell

currently i am rename my file with below command line i want to add alphabetic character to each file name  like file-a.jpg file-b.jpg

```
dir im* | ForEach-Object -begin { $count= 1 } -Process { Rename-Item $_ -newname
"img$count.jpg"; $count++}
```

Comment: What would happen if there's more than 26 files?

Comment: I think i can use below command but if you have any better solution then show me @techie007 
    dir *.jpg | foreach-object -begin { $count= 1 } -process {  rename-item $_ -Newname " image-$([char](64 + $count))$([char](96 + $count)).jpg"; $count++}'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `[char]` class to convert an integer to an ASCII character.

[ASCII code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) 97 is character `a`, so you could use 96 + the current loop count (`$count`); something like:

```
dir im* | ForEach-Object -begin { $count= 1 } -Process { Rename-Item $_ -newname
"file-$([char](96 + $count)).jpg"; $count++}
```

I haven't tested your/this code exactly, so you may have to fiddle with it a bit. :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"file-$([char](96 + $count)).jpg"`?

Comment: Probably. ;) Let me fix that..

Comment: @techie007 can you  please help me to understand what is meaning  of        $([char](96 + $count))  and   $count++   in this code ?  and by the way the code works perfectly for me

Comment: @raj `$()` means evaluate the contents and substitute them. It can be used within strings quoted with `"` quotes. `[char]` casts the value following it as an [ASCII code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) into a character. The value following it is `(96 + $count)`. ASCII code `97` is `a`, so when the variable `$count` is equal to `1`, you get `97` which is cast into `a`. `$count++` increments the `$count` variable (`++` increases the value of a variable by one).

Comment: Thanks for helping me and giving your valuable  time @Bob techie007

Comment: @raj I should warn you that special characters, possibly invalid in filenames, will start to appear after `z`, when `$count` exceeds `26`. You never did reply to techie007's comment on the question asking what to do in that case.